# How to apply a conditional to an E2E Test in CodeceptJS and NightmareJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, e2e-testing, codeceptjs

**What I need:**

Have an E2E Test in CodeceptJS with Nightmare as Main Helper verify the existence of an element, and depending on the result, continue doing a series of actions or others.

**Sample code:**

```
class EventsHelper extends Helper {

  isExistsElement(selector) {
    let browser = this.helpers['Nightmare'].browser;
    return browser.evaluate((selector) => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        let element = document.querySelector(selector);
        resolve(element || false);
      });
    }, selector);
  }
}
module.exports = EventsHelper;
```

---

```
Scenario('Test 1', async (I) => {
  const isButtonRendered = await I.isExistsElement('#button');

  if (isButtonRendered) {
    I.see('Message that is displayed only if the button exists.');
    I.click('#button');
  } else {
    I.see('Alternative message that appears if this button does not exist.');
  }
});
```

**The current result of this example code is:**
- If the button exists.

```
Evaluation timed out after 30000msec.  Are you calling done() or resolving your promises?
```

- Otherwise the button does not exist:
  PASS.

---

I am open to suggestions, corrections or different ideas to solve this problem.
Thank you all! (and excuse me if my English is not very clear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use custom helpers for the conditional itself, per the codeceptjs developers, they do not support conditionals inside the main scennario function.

Here is a custom helper example:

```
'use strict';
import assert from 'assert';

let Helper = codecept_helper;

class MyHelper extends Helper {
  async clickIfVisible(selector, ...options) {
    const helper = this.helpers['Puppeteer'];
    try {
      const numVisible = await helper.grabNumberOfVisibleElements(selector);

      if (numVisible) {
        return helper.click(selector, ...options);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Skipping operation as element is not visible');
    }
  }
}

module.exports = MyHelper;
```

More info: https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/issues/648